# PHP5.3 (as Apache module) unable to write into /var/www/<project-name>/<document-root>/cache

Tags: php, linux, apache, fedora, privileges

Please, be patient while reading, because the problem is seems to be transparent but just only seems.
The situation is:

1.

```
OS:     fedora-16 (latest),
httpd:  apache-2.2.21,
php:    php-5.3.8 (works as apache's module)
```

2.
    host information:

```
DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/[site-name]/public_html
Kohana-3.2.0 (latest stable) installed this way:

$ pwd
/var/www/<site-name>

$ ls -alp
drwxr-xr-x.  6 apache apache 4096 Jan   7 20:35 ./
drwxr-xr-x.  8 apache apache 4096 Jan   7 20:08 ../
drwxr-xr-x.  9 apache apache 4096 Jul  25 03:26 application/
drwxr-xr-x. 10 apache apache 4096 Jul  25 03:26 modules/
drwxr-xr-x.  2 apache apache 4096 Jan   7 20:35 public_html/
drwxr-xr-x. 11 apache apache 4096 Jul  25 03:26 system/

$ cd application/; ls -alp
drwxr-xr-x. 9 apache apache 4096 Jul  25 03:26 ./
drwxr-xr-x. 6 apache apache 4096 Jan   7 20:35 ../
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 apache apache 3612 Jul  25 03:22 bootstrap.php
drwxrwxrwx. 2 apache apache 4096 Jan   8 20:14 cache/
drwxr-xr-x. 4 apache apache 4096 Jul  25 03:26 classes/
drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache 4096 Jul  25 03:26 config/
drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache 4096 Jul  25 03:26 i18n/
drwxrwxrwx. 2 apache apache 4096 Jul  25 03:26 logs/
drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache 4096 Jul  25 03:26 messages/
drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache 4096 Jul  25 03:26 views/

Command `top` says that Apache is really starts under `apache` user privileges.
```

So how can I have that application/cache and application/logs directories are unwritable? - I've checked them also with

```
var_dump(fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../application/cache/something.txt', 'w+'));
```

Same result. Have no idea how it could be. No symlinks, no mounted drives etc.
Have anyone met such a situation?

Comment: If you checked the permissions: did you get any error message? Have you had a look at the server log to see some more error reporting than the one that might be shown in the browser?

Comment: They are 777 - technically any user will be able write on those folders. Is there a www-data user on your system?

Comment: yes - and that is the weird thing. I don't already hope on anybody knows how it could be, so if someone wants to buy my hard drive with this unique bug - you are welcome =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable selinux (http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html).

BTW from security standpoint, it's a very bad idea to make apache owner of .php files

Comment: Your solution sounds good, but I guess the situation I have shouldn't been happen - noone disables SELinux to install httpd, right? Any ideas how this could happen? Maybe there're some other way to solve the problem